# How to incorporate EDMX into solution effectively

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

One of the architects at my organization has provided me with an EDMX file for the web application I will be working on.

Another team will be making updates directly to the database at this time. Adding tables, changing columns etc.

How should I effectively incorporate this EDMX file into my solution?
So far, I used the file to generate the database locally and then did EF Code First from database.

This project is a little odd since another team will be making the db updates.

Thoughts?